# How to use checklist-model in edit mode?

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I'm using this directive to loop through some data when I create a `pop` so I can add the list checked to this object.
but the problem is how I can check the checkboxes that already in that object in the edit page (I use one HTML page for both create and edit):

```
<md-input-container ng-repeat="tab in allTabs">
    <md-checkbox aria-label="tab.name" checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab">
        {{tab.name}}
    </md-checkbox>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the existing objects are not mapping correctly - try using a 'track by' with the ng-repeat:

```
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="tab in allTabs track by tab.Id">
      <md-checkbox aria-label="tab.name" checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab">
        {{tab.name}}
      </md-checkbox>
    </md-input-container>
```

That should work 97% of the time. If you happen to fall in the 3% and you've been pulling your hair out for the last 3 days - try adding a comparator in your controller:

```
    $scope.compareFn = function(obj1, obj2){
        return obj1.id === obj2.id;
    };
```

And the 'checklist-comparator'

```
    <md-input-container ng-repeat="tab in allTabs track by tab.Id">
      <md-checkbox aria-label="tab.name" checklist-model="pop.tabs" checklist-value="tab" checklist-comparator="compareFn">
        {{tab.name}}
      </md-checkbox>
    </md-input-container>
```